# How do you identify this particular snake shedding?

Tags: skin, species-identification, herpetology

Aloha,

Snakes are illegal in the State of Hawaii, with the exception of the Hawaiian Blind Snake (Brahminy Blind Snake (Ramphotyhlops braminus)). I've read through a plethora of articles to no avail. It also doesn't help that snakes are virtually non-existent in the Hawaiian Islands.

I would like to identify this particular shedding, however, it has proven to be just as difficult as I predicted. Could anyone identify the species of this shedding?

Mahalo

[image: snake shedding]

[image: snake shedding2]